# Importing a custom entity from one solution to another

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom entity in one of my solutions which I need in another.  How do I go about importing an entity from one solution to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be as easy as using the "Add Existing" button in the Solution - Entities view.

Comment: So I've been told, however I had both solutions in the solutions window, clicked 'Add Existing' and nothing appeared other than the standard entities.  Any chance of a 'Step-By-Step' to make sure I'm not making some rookie mistake?

Comment: Are they on the same organization (tenant)?

Comment: Find the Solution that has the custom entity in. Make sure the entity is published (or just publish all if you know there are not loads of draft changes in the system). Now in the target solution you should be able to use "Add Existing" to add a link to the new entity